# MongoDB combine collections or have multiple references

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema, mongodb-query

I have a set of categories that a user can choose from (movies, music, books, etc) and rate items within the selected category.

Because each category has different parameters (`movies` has `year`, `music` has `artist`, etc) I figured split up each category into it's own collection, however, that brings up the problem of having to reference to the correct document in the ratings collection (Option 1).

Would it be smarter to keep all categories separated and have a bunch of references in the ratings collection? Or to combine all categories into a single collection where each document would have most of the parameters blank (option 2)?

EDIT: I suppose another option would be to have each category have their own ratings collection (i.e. `MovieRatings`) but that would get a bit cluttered...

---

OPTION 1:

Items:

```
Movies = {
  title: String,
  year: Number,
  imageUrl: String
}

Music = {
  title: String,
  artist: String,
  imageUrl: String
}
```

Ratings:

```
Ratings = {
  user: ObjectId,
  movie: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Movies' },
  music: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Music' },
  ...
  rating: Number
}
```

---

OPTION 2:

Items:

```
Items = {
  title: String,
  artist: String,
  year: Number,
  imageUrl: String
}
```

Ratings:

```
Ratings = {
  user: ObjectId,
  item: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Items' },
  rating: Number
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I suggest neither? :) You are probably still thinking about how you'd model this problem in RDBMS, but MongoDB is a completely different animal. You want to avoid references whenever possible, and you can do so in this example.

Inside your `users` collection, you can have an array of `ratings`, and each `rating` should describe whether a movie or music item was rated, together with the rating score itself.

Something like this will give you much better performance:

`{"_id": "sherlock@holmes.net",
 "ratings": [{
    "type": "movie",
    "title": String,
    "year": Number,
    "imageUrl": String,
    "rating": Number
  }, {
    "type": "music",
    "title": String,
    "artist": String,
    "imageUrl": String,
    "rating": Number
 }]
}`

Note that depending on how you want to query or generate this data, you may benefit from *other* schemas. This is just an example to help get you used to thinking in denormalized terms — the way MongoDB wants you to store data.

Comment: So you're saying it would be ok to have parameters (titles, image url's) repeat across collections? What if, for instance, I were to later modify a movie title/image? I would have to update each user's ratings with the new parameters, too...

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Duplication is an inevitable part of denormalization. In some cases, that matters, but in this case, perhaps not -- if you modify a title / image, is that "new" title / image *really* the same one to the user who rated it? Not necessarily. The user should probably be given a chance to rate that one again. In fact, if you're community maintained site, then there's a chance a user could take a movie with many ratings and change the title / picture to something obscene!